# Html form submits to current page url using GET instead of method and action defined in form

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a form in blade template that submits with a GET method instead of POST method. The form allows registered and unregistered users to submit the data but it only works when a user is logged in. For new users I get the error as show in the image below

[image]

Here is the html form:

```
    @auth
        <div class="checkout-main-area pt-120 pb-120">
            <div class="container">

                <form id="place-order-form" action="{{ route('order.store') }}" method="post">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="checkout-wrap pt-30">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-7">
                                <div class="billing-info-wrap mr-50">
                                    <h3>Billing Details</h3>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                                            <div class="billing-info mb-20">
                                                <label>Names <abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr></label>
                                                <input type="text" name="name" disabled value="{{ $user->name }}">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                                            <div class="billing-info mb-20">
                                                <label>Display name <abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr></label>
                                                <input type="text" name="display_name" disabled
                                                    value="{{ $user->display_name }}">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                                            <div class="billing-info mb-20">
                                                <label>Your Address <abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr></label>
                                                <input name="address" class="billing-address"
                                                    placeholder="House number and street name" type="text"
                                                    value="{{ $user->address()->address_1 ?? '' }}">

                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                                            <div class="billing-info mb-20">
                                                <label>Phone <abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr></label>
                                                <input name="telephone" type="text" value="{{ $user->telephone }}">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                                            <div class="billing-info mb-20">
                                                <label>Email Address <abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr></label>
                                                <input type="email" name="email" disabled value="{{ $user->email }}">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="additional-info-wrap">
                                        <label>Order notes</label>
                                        <textarea placeholder="Notes about your order, e.g. special notes for delivery. " name="order_note"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-5">
                                <div class="your-order-area">
                                    <h3>Your order</h3>
                                    <div class="your-order-wrap gray-bg-4">
                                        <div class="your-order-info-wrap">
                                            <div class="your-order-info">
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li>Product <span>Total</span></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="your-order-middle">
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li>{{ $product->name }} X {{ $quantity }} <span>TZS
                                                            {{ $product->price * $quantity }} </span></li>
                                       
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="your-order-info order-subtotal">
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li>Subtotal <span>TZS {{ $product->price * $quantity }} </span></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="your-order-info order-total">
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li>Total <span>TZS {{ $product->price * $quantity }} </span></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="payment-method">
                                            <div class="pay-top sin-payment">
                                                <input id="payment_method_1" class="input-radio" type="radio" value="cheque"
                                                    checked="checked" name="payment_method">
                                                <label for="payment_method_1"> LIPA number </label>
                                                <div class="payment-box payment_method_bacs">
                                                    <p>->Make your payment through LIPA number <strong>7886754</strong>.
                                                        <br>->Then send us your payment message with phone number and email
                                                        through
                                                        {{ App\Models\Setting::where('key', 'contact_number')->first()->value }}
                                                    </p>
                                                    <br>Record these instructions before placing order.
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="product" value="{{ $product->id }}">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="{{ $quantity }}">
                                    <div class="Place-order">
                                        <a href="javascript:{}"
                                            onclick="document.getElementById('place-order-form').submit();">Procceed</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    @else
        <div class="checkout-main-area pt-50 pb-120">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="customer-zone mb-0">

                    <p class="cart-page-title">Returning customer? <a class="checkout-click" target="_blank" href="{{ route('login') }}">Click
                            here to login</a> Then refresh this page.</p>


                </div>
             
<form method="post" id="place-order-form" action="{{ route('order.store') }}" >
                    @csrf
                    
                    <div class="checkout-wrap pt-30">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-7">
                                <div class="billing-info-wrap mr-50">
                                    <h3>Billing Details</h3>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                                            <div class="billing-info mb-20">
                                                <label>Names <abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr></label>
                                                <input required type="text" name="name">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
                                            <div class="billing-info mb-20">
                                                <label>Display name <abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr></label>
                                                <input required type="text" name="display_name">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                                            <div class="billing-info mb-20">
                                                <label>Your Password <abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr></label>
                                                <input required name="password" class="billing-address"
                                                    placeholder="Enter your password" type="password">

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                                            <div class="billing-info mb-20">
                                                <label>Your Address <abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr></label>
                                                <input required name="address" class="billing-address"
                                                    placeholder="House number and street name" type="text">

                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                                            <div class="billing-info mb-20">
                                                <label>Phone <abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr></label>
                                                <input required name="telephone" type="text">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
                                            <div class="billing-info mb-20">
                                                <label>Email Address <abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr></label>
                                                <input required type="email" name="email">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="additional-info-wrap">
                                        <label>Order notes</label>
                                        <textarea placeholder="Notes about your order, e.g. special notes for delivery. " name="order_note"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-5">
                                <div class="your-order-area">
                                    <h3>Your order</h3>
                                    <div class="your-order-wrap gray-bg-4">
                                        <div class="your-order-info-wrap">
                                            <div class="your-order-info">
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li>Product <span>Total Sum</span></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="your-order-middle">
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li>{{ $product->name }} X {{ $quantity }} <span>TZS
                                                            {{ $product->price * $quantity }} </span></li>

                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="your-order-info order-subtotal">
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li>Subtotal <span>TZS {{ $product->price * $quantity }} </span></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="your-order-info order-total">
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li>Total <span>TZS {{ $product->price * $quantity }} </span></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="payment-method">
                                            <div class="pay-top sin-payment">
                                                <input id="payment_method_1" class="input-radio" type="radio"
                                                    value="cheque" checked="checked" name="payment_method">
                                                <label for="payment_method_1"> LIPA number </label>
                                                <div class="payment-box payment_method_bacs">
                                                    <p>->Make your payment through TIGO LIPA number <strong>7886754</strong>.
                                                        <br>->Then send us your payment message with phone number and email
                                                        through
                                                        {{ App\Models\Setting::where('key', 'contact_number')->first()->value }}
                                                    </p>
                                                    <br>Record these instructions before placing order.
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="product" value="{{ $product->id }}">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="{{ $quantity }}">
                                    <div class="Place-order">
                                        <a href="javascript:{}"
                                            onclick="document.getElementById('place-order-form').submit();">Procceed</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
               
                

            </div>
        </div>
    @endauth
```

Here are the defined routes in web.php:

```
Route::post('/order/create', [OrderController::class, 'create'])->name('order.create');
Route::post('order/store', [ OrderController::class, 'store' ])->name('order.store');
Route::get('/order/lipa', [ OrderController::class, 'lipa' ])->name('order.lipa');
Route::post('/order/status/update', [ OrderController::class, 'order_status' ])->name('order.status.update');
```

And here is the OrderController:

```
<?php


class OrderController extends Controller
{
   
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->type != 'all') {
            $orders = Order::where('status', $request->type)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
        } else {
            $orders = Order::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
        }
        
        $title = 'All Orders';
        
        return view('admin.orders.index', compact('title', 'orders'));
    }

    
    public function create(Request $request)
    {
        
        (Auth::check()) ? $user = Auth::user() : $user = [] ;
        $product_ = Product::find($request->product);
        
        return view('front.order.index', [ 'user' => $user, 'product' => $product_, 'quantity' => $request->qtybutton, ]);
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        
        if (!Auth::check()) {
            $this->validate($request, [
                'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
                'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
                'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
                'display_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
                'telephone' => 'required|string|max:255',
                'address' => 'required|string|max:255',
            ]);
            $user = User::create([
                'name' => $request->name,
                'email' => $request->email,
                'telephone' => $request->telephone,
                'display_name' => $request->display_name,
                'password' => Hash::make($request->password)
            ]);
            $user->assignRole(RolesCONST::ROLE_USER);
            $user->address()->create([
                'address_1' => $request->address
            ]);
            Order::create([
                'user_id' => $user->id,
                'product_id' => $request->product,
                'quantity' => $request->quantity,
                'order_note' => $request->order_note
            ]);
        } else {
            if ($request->address != '') {
                $user = Auth::user();
                $user->address()->update([
                    'address_1' => $request->address
                ]);
            }
            if ($request->telephone != '') {
                $user = Auth::user();
                $user->update([
                    'telephone' => $request->telephone
                ]);
            }
            Order::create([
                'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
                'product_id' => $request->product,
                'quantity' => $request->quantity,
                'order_note' => $request->order_note
            ]);
        }
        
        return redirect()->route('order.lipa')->withCookie(cookie('order', $request->product,45));
    }

    public function lipa(Request $request){
        $telephone = Setting::where('key', 'contact_number')->first()->value;
        if ($request->hasCookie('order')) {
            $product_ = $request->cookie('order');
            $product = Product::find($product_);
            return view('front.order.lipa', compact('product', 'telephone'));
        } else {
            return redirect()->route('index')->with('error', 'No product selected');
        }
        
    }

    public function order_status(Request $request)
    {
        

        $order = Order::find($request->order_id);
        $order->update([
            'status' => $request->status
        ]);
        return redirect()->route('shop.index')->with('success', 'Order status updated');
    }

    

    
}
```

I tried pasting the code in first branch of @auth but still getting the same results. I have the method and action defined but still facing the same problem. I tried passing through other answers but most explain on defining the method but this appears to be a specific case

I noticed that the form is returned from a post request that passes data to the current url `/order/create` but I am not sure if that is a problem or not because on submit the form makes a GET request to the same url of the current page.

I also tried submitting using javascript as so:

```
 function submitForm(e){
            console.log('Submitting form')
            e.preventDefault()
           document.getElementById('place-order-form').submit()
        }
```

But the form still submits to `order/create` instead of `order/store`

This is a codebase that I have been given recently to maintain and I am totally not sure what the possible cause is

Comment: Could it be that `create` route should be GET in route file?

Comment: I thought so too but am not very sure if its the possible case. I initially thought it could be a security measure to transfer the product_id and quantity.

Comment: Try to clear all cache backend and frontend. Backend you can execute `php artisan optimize:clear` command.

Comment: check your blade file if that you have only one form tag with the Id: `<form id="place-order-form" >`

Comment: I tried clearing cache as @Tpojka suggested but still getting the same error.

Comment: I inspected also but there is only one form with id `place-order-form`